# Caesar's cipher decoder works but Valgrind shows many errors

Tags: c, caesar-cipher

The program is a [Caesar's cipher](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caesar_cipher) decoder. It compiles and works ok, but in Valgrind, I receive a lot of errors and I have no idea how to solve them.

I have tried with --track-origins=yes, but I still have no clue what's wrong.

Example to test: xUbbemehbT, XYlloworld -> Helloworld.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

#define MODE_1 1
#define MODE_2 2

enum Error
{
    ERROR_INPUT = 100,
    ERROR_LENGTH = 101
};

enum Msg
{
    DEFAULT_LEN = 10,
    LAST_LOWER = 26,
    LAST_UPPER = 52
};

int mandatory(void);
int optional(void);

void sub_shift(char *message, char mode);
char *shift(char *original, char *misheard);
int compute_shift(char *original, char *misheard, size_t len, int shift_1);
int compare_by_symbol(const char *msg1, const char *msg2, int length);
int free_and_exit(char *msg1, char *msg2, int error);

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int ret = EXIT_SUCCESS;

    bool prp_optional = argc > 1 ? strcmp(argv[1], "-prp-optional") == 0 : false;

    prp_optional ? optional(), ret = optional() : mandatory(), ret = mandatory();

    return ret;
}

void sub_shift(char *message, char mode)
{
    size_t len = strlen(message) - 1; // -1 Because of '\0'
    if (mode == MODE_1)
    {
        for (size_t letter = 0; letter < len; letter++)
        {
            if (message[letter] > 'Z' + 1)
            {
                message[letter] -= 'G';
            }
            else
            {
                message[letter] -= 'A';
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        for (size_t letter = 0; letter < len; letter++)
        {
            if (message[letter] > LAST_LOWER)
            {
                message[letter] += 'G';
            }
            else
            {
                message[letter] += 'A';
            }
        }
    }
}

char *shift(char *original, char *misheard)
{
    int shift_1 = 0;
    size_t len = strlen(original) - 1; // -1 Because of '\0'

    sub_shift(original, MODE_1);
    sub_shift(misheard, MODE_1);

    shift_1 = compute_shift(original, misheard, len, shift_1);
    
    for (size_t letter = 0; letter < len; letter++)
    {
        original[letter] += shift_1;
        original[letter] %= LAST_UPPER;
    }

    sub_shift(original, MODE_2);
    original[len] = '\0'; // Remove the last character

    return original;
}

int compute_shift(char *original, char *misheard, size_t len, int shift_1)
{
    int off = 0;
    for (int index = 0; index <= LAST_UPPER; index++)
    {
        int offset = 0;
        for (size_t letter = 0; letter < len; letter++)
        {
            original[letter]++;
            original[letter] %= LAST_UPPER;

            if (original[letter] == misheard[letter])
            {
                offset++;
            }
        }
        if (off < offset)
        {
            off = offset;
            shift_1 = index;
        }
    }

    return shift_1;
}

int compare_by_symbol(const char *msg1, const char *msg2, int length)
{
    int equal_counter = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
        if (msg1[i] == msg2[i])
        {
            equal_counter++;
        }
    }
    return equal_counter;
}

int free_and_exit(char *msg1, char *msg2, int error)
{
    free(msg1);
    free(msg2);
    msg1 = NULL;
    msg2 = NULL;
    if (error == ERROR_INPUT)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error: Wrong input!\n");
        exit(ERROR_INPUT);
    }
    else if (error == ERROR_LENGTH)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error: Wrong input length!\n");
        exit(ERROR_LENGTH);
    }
    else
    {
        free(msg1);
        free(msg2);
        msg1 = NULL;
        msg2 = NULL;
        exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
    }
}

int mandatory(void)
{
    int ret = EXIT_SUCCESS;

    size_t capacity = DEFAULT_LEN;
    int positions[LAST_UPPER];

    size_t len1 = 0;
    size_t len2 = 0;

    char *msg1 = (char *)malloc(capacity);
    char *msg2 = (char *)malloc(capacity);

    while ((msg1[len1] = getchar()) != EOF && msg1[len1] != '\n')
    {
        // If is not in an alphabet (not a letter a-zA-Z)
        if (!isalpha(msg1[len1]))
        {
            ret = free_and_exit(msg1, msg2, ERROR_INPUT);
        }
        // Extend if exceed capacity
        if (++len1 == capacity)
        {
            msg1 = (char *)realloc(msg1, capacity * 2);
        }
    }
    while ((msg2[len2] = getchar()) != EOF && msg2[len2] != '\n')
    {
        // If is not in an alphabet (not a letter a-zA-Z)
        if (!isalpha(msg2[len2]))
        {
            ret = free_and_exit(msg1, msg2, ERROR_INPUT);
        }
        // Extend if exceed capacity
        if (++len2 == capacity)
        {
            msg2 = (char *)realloc(msg2, capacity * 2);
        }
    }
    if (len1 != len2)
    {
        ret = free_and_exit(msg1, msg2, ERROR_LENGTH);
    }

    char *msg_temp = (char *)malloc(len1);

    for (int offset = 0; offset < LAST_UPPER; offset++)
    {
        strcpy(msg_temp, msg1);

        positions[offset] = compare_by_symbol(msg_temp, msg2, len2);
    }

    int last_offset = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < LAST_UPPER; i++)
    {
        if (positions[i] > last_offset)
        {
            last_offset = i;
        }
    }
    // Final decode
    msg1 = shift(msg1, msg2);

    // Print decoded message
    printf("%s\n", msg1);

    free(msg_temp);
    msg_temp = NULL;
    ret = free_and_exit(msg1, msg2, EXIT_SUCCESS);

    return ret;
}

int optional(void)
{
    /* Same as mandatory, only length comparison check is removed */
    int ret = EXIT_SUCCESS
    size_t capacity = DEFAULT_LEN;
    int positions[LAST_UPPER];

    size_t len1 = 0;
    size_t len2 = 0;

    char *msg1 = (char *)malloc(capacity);
    char *msg2 = (char *)malloc(capacity);

    while ((msg1[len1] = getchar()) != EOF && msg1[len1] != '\n')
    {
        // If is not in an alphabet (not a letter)
        if (!isalpha(msg1[len1]))
        {
            ret = free_and_exit(msg1, msg2, ERROR_INPUT);
        }
        // Extend if exceed capacity
        if (++len1 == capacity)
        {
            msg1 = (char *)realloc(msg1, capacity * 2);
        }
    }
    while ((msg2[len2] = getchar()) != EOF && msg2[len2] != '\n')
    {
        // If is not in an alphabet (not a letter)
        if (!isalpha(msg2[len2]))
        {
            ret = free_and_exit(msg1, msg2, ERROR_INPUT);
        }
        // Extend if exceed capacity
        if (++len2 == capacity)
        {
            msg2 = (char *)realloc(msg2, capacity * 2);
        }
    }

    char *msg_temp = (char *)malloc(len1);

    for (int offset = 0; offset < LAST_UPPER; offset++)
    {
        strcpy(msg_temp, msg1);

        positions[offset] = compare_by_symbol(msg_temp, msg2, len2);
    }

    int last_offset = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < LAST_UPPER; i++)
    {
        if (positions[i] > last_offset)
        {
            last_offset = i;
        }
    }
    // Final decode
    msg1 = shift(msg1, msg2);

    // Print decoded message
    printf("%s\n", msg1);

    free(msg_temp);
    msg_temp = NULL;
    ret = free_and_exit(msg1, msg2, EXIT_SUCCESS);

    return ret;
}
```

EDIT: Valgrind output.

> ==1308== Memcheck, a memory error detector
> ==1308== Copyright (C) 2002-2017, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
> ==1308== Using Valgrind-3.15.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
> ==1308== Command: ./main
> ==1308== \ xUbbemehbT\ XYlloworld
> ==1308== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
> ==1308==    at 0x483F0B7: strcpy (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
> ==1308==    by 0x10BAB2: strcpy (string_fortified.h:90)
> ==1308==    by 0x10BAB2: mandatory (main.c:214)
> ==1308==    by 0x1091CC: main (main.c:38)
> ==1308==  Uninitialised value was created by a heap allocation
> ==1308==    at 0x483B7F3: malloc (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
> ==1308==    by 0x10B9B7: mandatory (main.c:176)
> ==1308==    by 0x1091CC: main (main.c:38)
> ==1308== 
> ==1308== Invalid write of size 1
> ==1308==    at 0x483F0BE: strcpy (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
> ==1308==    by 0x10BAB2: strcpy (string_fortified.h:90)
> ==1308==    by 0x10BAB2: mandatory (main.c:214)
> ==1308==    by 0x1091CC: main (main.c:38)
> ==1308==  Address 0x4a495eb is 0 bytes after a block of size 11 alloc'd
> ==1308==    at 0x483B7F3: malloc (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
> ==1308==    by 0x10BA9F: mandatory (main.c:210)
> ==1308==    by 0x1091CC: main (main.c:38)
> ==1308== 
> ==1308== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
> ==1308==    at 0x483EF58: strlen (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
> ==1308==    by 0x10983F: shift (main.c:79)
> ==1308==    by 0x10BAC2: mandatory (main.c:228)
> ==1308==    by 0x1091CC: main (main.c:38)
> ==1308==  Uninitialised value was created by a heap allocation
> ==1308==    at 0x483B7F3: malloc (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
> ==1308==    by 0x10B9B7: mandatory (main.c:176)
> ==1308==    by 0x1091CC: main (main.c:38)
> ==1308== 
> ==1308== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
> ==1308==    at 0x483EF58: strlen (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
> ==1308==    by 0x109AB8: sub_shift (main.c:45)
> ==1308==    by 0x109AB8: shift (main.c:82)
> ==1308==    by 0x10BAC2: mandatory (main.c:228)
> ==1308==    by 0x1091CC: main (main.c:38)
> ==1308==  Uninitialised value was created by a heap allocation
> ==1308==    at 0x483B7F3: malloc (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
> ==1308==    by 0x10B9C4: mandatory (main.c:177)
> ==1308==    by 0x1091CC: main (main.c:38)
> ==1308== 
> ==1308== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
> ==1308==    at 0x483EF58: strlen (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
> ==1308==    by 0x10AA4E: sub_shift (main.c:45)
> ==1308==    by 0x10AA4E: shift (main.c:92)
> ==1308==    by 0x10BAC2: mandatory (main.c:228)
> ==1308==    by 0x1091CC: main (main.c:38)
> ==1308==  Uninitialised value was created by a heap allocation
> ==1308==    at 0x483B7F3: malloc (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
> ==1308==    by 0x10B9B7: mandatory (main.c:176)
> ==1308==    by 0x1091CC: main (main.c:38)
> ==1308== \ Helloworld
> ==1308== 
> ==1308== HEAP SUMMARY:
> ==1308==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
> ==1308==   total heap usage: 5 allocs, 5 frees, 2,261 bytes allocated
> ==1308== 
> ==1308== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
> ==1308== 
> ==1308== For lists of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -s
> ==1308== ERROR SUMMARY: 107 errors from 5 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)

Comment: `size_t len = strlen(message) - 1; // -1 Because of '\0'`  That doesn't make sense, since `strlen` does not count the terminator.

Comment: Here's one problem:  `char *msg_temp = (char *)malloc(len1);`  It appears `len1` is the count of characters, and does not include room for the terminator.

Comment: Please tell us more about the purpose of the code.

Comment: Code decodes first input based on how it is similar to the second input which is changed original message. Thanks JDlugosz, now there are a bit less errors

Comment: Welcome to CR! I am too lazy to compile and run in Valgrind, can you share the Valgrind output at the bottom of your question?

Comment: Added valgrind output

Comment: Solved: Added msg1[len1] = '\0'; lines after while ((msg1[len1] = getchar()) != EOF && msg1[len1] != '\n') loops in mandatory and optional functions

Comment: When you have fixed the code to work to your satisfaction, please do bring it back for review - there are many problems (including bugs) in this code, only some of which are addressed in the existing answers.

Comment: @sznailc given your update from 21 hours ago, Are you open to [feedback about any or all facets of the code](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)? If so, then please [edit] the post to contain the working code (with errors removed).

Comment: I really don't understand what this program is supposed to do.  Comparing two inputs?  I expect a Ceasar Cypher decoder/encoder to take a string and a shift count, and produce the transformed string.

Answer (score 1):

```
    /* Same as mandatory, only length comparison check is removed */
```

Don't do that.  You duplicated the entire (complex) function to make minor changes; specifically to skip error checks.

Write one copy of the function.  Put the optional checks in another preliminary function that's called first, or pass a boolean parameter to enable/disable the tests.

You might reconsider whether you want a version that doesn't do error checking.  Are these tests super expensive compared to the work being done?

Comment: I'll change it, but it is not the main problem now

Answer (score 1):

**Avoid subtraction with *unsigned* math**

When `message[0] == 0` and `size_t len = strlen(message) - 1;`, `len` takes on the value of `SIZE_MAX`.  Instead:

```
void sub_shift(char *message, char mode) {
  // size_t len = strlen(message) - 1;
  size_t len = strlen(message);
  if (mode == MODE_1)
  {
    // for (size_t letter = 0; letter < len; letter++)
    for (size_t letter = 0; letter + 1 < len; letter++)
```

**Use consistent types**

`length` deserves to be `size_t` to match calling code and for the best type to use with string lengths.

```
size_t compare_by_symbol(const char *msg1, const char *msg2, size_t length) {
  size_t equal_counter = 0;
  for (size_t  i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    if (msg1[i] == msg2[i]) {
      equal_counter++;
    }
  }
  return equal_counter;
}
```